# magento product detail pages are blank

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Facing an issue with [magento store product](https://biotone.com/massage-products/creme/advanced-therapy-massage-creme) detail page. Browser console is only showing error below. Nothing has been updated to the extension referenced below. Any direction to identify the issue would be appreciated.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElements' of null
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (scp_product_extension.js:519)
at HTMLDocument.responder (prototype.js:5575)
at fire (prototype.js:5734)
at HTMLDocument._methodized [as fire] (prototype.js:438)
at HTMLDocument.fireContentLoadedEvent (prototype.js:5820)
```

The exception.log shows

```
2016-12-20T14:21:52+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Parse error reading getAccessToken 
HTTP response!' in  var/www/vhosts/biotone.com/httpdocs/app/Mage.php:595
```

Comment: first disabled the scp_product [simple configurable product] extension and clear cache than check

Comment: check in default theme , also check other products by changin design to blank, default....etc....